# Intellij autocomplete failing on multiplatform library dependencies

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, kotlin-multiplatform

I've created a multiplatform library that I consume in a different multiplatform project. After including the dependency I am able to use the libraries in commonMain without issue and all targets build without errors. However, intellij autocomplete does not know about my new types. I have invalidated caches and restarted the application many times, but it just cannot find this type. Anybody encountered this?

[image: Intellij reports errors]

[image: but gradle shows success]

just in case, here is my build.gradle.kts:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.targets.js.webpack.KotlinWebpack

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.3.61"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven(  "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/ktor" )
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

val ktor_version = "1.1.3"
val logback_version = "1.2.3"

kotlin {
    js {
        browser {  }
    }
    jvm {
        compilations.named("main") {
            tasks.getByName<Copy>(processResourcesTaskName) {
                dependsOn("jsBrowserWebpack")
                tasks.named<KotlinWebpack>("jsBrowserWebpack") {
                    from(entry.name, destinationDirectory)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("stdlib-common"))
                api("github.fatalcatharsis:constraint:1.0-SNAPSHOT")
            }
        }

        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }

        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation( kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
                implementation( "io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version")
                implementation( "io.ktor:ktor-html-builder:$ktor_version")
                implementation( "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version")
            }
        }

        val jvmTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-testng"))
            }
        }

        val jsMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation( kotlin("stdlib-js"))
            }
        }

        val jsTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation( kotlin("test-js"))
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.register<JavaExec>("run") {
    dependsOn("jvmJar")
    group = "application"
    main = "sample.SampleJvmKt"
    val t = tasks.named<Jar>("jvmJar")

    classpath(configurations.named("jvmRuntimeClasspath"), t.get() )
}
```

Comment: Do you see that dependency in "Project Structure | Modules - Dependencies"? What scope is set for it?

Comment: In the common module, it shows up as constraint-metadata. On the jvm module, it shows up as constraint-jvm. On the js module it shows up constraint-js. The type autocomplete works in the latter 2, but not the former. They all have scope "compile". All 3 targets build, just that intellij doesn't recognize the type in the common module

Comment: Please report an issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-230647. after picking away at it for a bit, I started thinking it was defect rather than a configuration issue. I'll leave the question open in case anyone else has insight, and once I get it diagnosed and potentially resolved, I'll close this question.